# Filtering a Pandas pivot table *during* the pivot

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume we have the following data frame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'food' : ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'ham', 'ham', 'eggs', 'milk'],
                   'sales' : [10, 15, 12, 5, 14, 3, 8]})
```

I'd like to pivot this data to show the sum of `sales` by `food`, **but only if `sales` is greater than 12**.  The resulting pivot table would look as follows:

Unfiltered df:

```
food       sum(sales)
spam       10
ham        34
eggs       15
milk       8
```

Filtered df:

```
food       sum(sales)
ham        34
eggs       15
```

I can use `groupby()` as follows:

```
df_new.groupby(['food'])['sales'].agg('sum') > 12
```

But, this only gives me the boolean and not the filtered `df`.

Is this possible to filter a column "on the fly" when using the `pd.pivot_table()` function? (i.e. without pre-filtering the `df`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a lambda function `.loc` which will filter the dataframe for only rows that match the condition that the lambda function returns:

```
filtered = df.groupby('food')['sales'].sum().reset_index().loc[lambda x: x['sales'] > 12]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
   food  sales
0  eggs     15
1   ham     34
```

(In case you're wondering, the lambda function gets executed for the whole dataframe, not for each individual row, so yes, it's very efficient :)

Comment: This works beautifully.  How would you output only the `food` column?

Comment: Use `.loc[lambda x: x['sales'] > 12, ['food']]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` produces a series object.
It's not pretty, but you can subset it dynamically using:

`df.groupby(['food'])['sales'].agg('sum')[df.groupby(['food'])['sales'].agg('sum')>12]`

Comment: Nice, but I recommend storing the return value of `groupby` in a separate variable, because `groupby`s can be expensive.